# C'est pas très beau le passé simple!

Tags: passé-simple

Je trouve que ce n'est pas très beau de dire et même de lire

> Nous leur donnâmes un verre d'eau.

Ce n'est plus du tout employé aujourd'hui ; c'est désuet.

Par quoi pourrait-on remplacer cette forme ?

Comment: On peut le trouver utile pour les jeux de mots quand même ... « Ah, pourquoi n'ai-je pas choisi un Ford quand j'ai eu l'occasion ? Maintenant je n'ai que cet espèce de Volkswagen. — Alors, vous passâtes. »

Comment: @LukeSawczak Même chose pour le subjonctif imparfait, n'est-ce pas? *«Docteur! Ma femme est clouée au lit! J'aimerais que vous la vissiez!»*

Comment: excellent … Mais ne jetons pas le bébé avec l'eau du bain, nous perdrions beaucoup en abandonnant le passé simple et l'imparfait du subjonctif, en particulier bien sûr à l'écrit.

Answer (score 3):

Je me doutais bien que Cyrano (Rostand) avait employé le passé simple à un moment clé de la *tirade des nez* quand il taille en pièces par son éloquence son adversaire le vicomte, et en commentaires on s'est aussi amusé avec l'imparfait du subjonctif et donc je souligne les deux temps (omettant le plus-que-parfait du subjonctif) :

> [...] Mais d’esprit, ô le plus lamentable des êtres,
>  Vous n’en
>   **eûtes** jamais un atome, et de lettres
>  Vous n’avez que les trois qui forment le mot : sot !
>   Eussiez-vous eu, d’ailleurs, l’invention qu’il faut
>  Pour pouvoir là, devant ces nobles galeries,
>  Me servir toutes ces
>   folles plaisanteries,
>  Que vous n’en **eussiez** pas articulé le
>   quart
>  De la moitié du commencement d’une, car
>  Je me les sers
>   moi-même, avec assez de verve,
>  Mais je ne permets pas qu’un autre
>   me les serve.
>
> [*Cyrano de Bergerac*](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyrano_de_Bergerac_(Rostand)), E. Rostand ([Acte I, Scène IV](https://fr.wikisource.org/wiki/Cyrano_de_Bergerac_(Rostand)/Acte_I))

Je trouve que le tout coule et sonne particulièrement bien, que c'est ontologiquement euphonique et que c'est d'une facture  exceptionnelle et d'une richesse immense que ce français-là, au point que si le temps n'existait que pour savourer cette tirade, ça me suffirait sans doute. Mais il se trouve que c'est aussi utilisé dans une chanson folklorique (québécoise) basée sur un conte bien connu ([la Chasse-galerie](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chasse-galerie)) :

> Vous connaissez l'histoire :
>  Nous bûchions au chantier 
>  Loin
>   de nos être chers
>  Dix gars ben esseulés
>  Dans notre
>   désespoir
>   Le soir du jour de l'An
>  Nous avons fait
>   Ciboire
>   Un pacte avec Satan
>  Dans le ciel du pays
>   Le
>   canot **fendit** l'air
>   Et nous **mena** ravis
>   Aux maison
>   de nos pères
>  Tout'la nuit en famille
>  Nous **pûmes** rire et
>   boire
>  Mais sans toucher aux filles
>  Le diab' veut rien
>   savoir. [...]
>
> [[*Martin de la Chasse-Galerie*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=efpdOA4y5IE), La Bottine Souriante, La
>   Mistrine, 1994]

On aime le lire, on aime l'entendre, on aime le chanter... Enfin en ce qui a trait plus particulièrement à l'écrit contemporain, « le passé simple reste extrêmement vivant et productif aux troisièmes personnes du singulier et du pluriel » et « [p]ar conséquent, malgré les efforts de certains écrivains français, depuis le milieu du XXe siècle, pour prôner l'usage du passé composé ou du présent de narration, le passé simple reste encore aujourd'hui le temps par excellence des romans narrés à la troisième personne » (Wikipédia, [passé simple](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pass%C3%A9_simple_en_fran%C3%A7ais#D%C3%A9clin_du_pass%C3%A9_simple_et_rar%C3%A9faction_%C3%A0_l'oral)).

---

On a constaté son déclin à l'oral, mais on aime le passé simple, pour soutenir l'éloquence ou avoir le choix de l'archaïsme, entre autres, et il demeure certainement utile aujourd'hui, plus particulièrement à l'écrit, presque exclusivement à la troisième personne et il est irremplaçable en littérature française.

Comment: Merci pour votre belle réponse, qui m’a incité à ajouter à la mienne. Rien ne vaut des exemples pour étayer un argument sur l’utilité ou la possibilité d’un fait de langue, et même si l’on ne peut déclarer unilatéralement la beauté ou la laideur d’une tournure, on peut du moins en offrir des morceaux que l’on juge élégants, aux autres de voir pour eux par la suite.

Answer (score 2):

Le passé simple est directement issu du parfait latin, lui-même complété par le passé composé issu du bas-latin. Le trouver laid est simplement un manque d'habitude, voire de pratique ; il est vrai que c'est une forme qu'on trouve à l'écrit (et pas rarement ! ou alors nous n'avons pas les mêmes lectures …) et non à l'oral : c'est le passé historique.

Il y a quelque analogie avec la problématique du subjonctif, quoi qu'il en soit nous perdrions beaucoup à son abandon – hélas, nous autres, langues, nous savons maintenant que nous sommes mortelles (merci Paul Valéry).

Dans votre exemple, aucune objection à le remplacer par le passé composé, en gardant à l'esprit que les deux temps ont chacun leur utilité.